# Problem with encoding when use insertBefore in DOMDcocument with WordPress response

Tags: php, wordpress, xpath, domdocument

I have a php variable with html, I want to make some changes with DomDocument, like insert a new tag with:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->insertBefore($new_element, $first_child);
```

everything work fine but when are present special characters like à,è,ò the response is a character like �

I tried with the classic directive like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> before html content
```

or `DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8')`

or `utf8_decode()`

this resolve the problem in general of all html content, but when I made the changes with

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->insertBefore($new_element, $first_child);
```

it returns these characters like `�` for this new hmtl element added

here my code:

$html content is a return of `get_the_content()` in wordpress

```
$nomiClassi = array('namea', 'nameb');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
        
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($nomiClassi as $nomeClasse) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='$nomeClasse']");
    
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}

$new_element = $dom->createElement('h2', get_the_title()  );
$first_child = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->firstChild;
$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->insertBefore($new_element, $first_child);
$newHtml = utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement) );
```

some advice ?

Comment: advice: consult the manual when you've got a problem with a method in use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php -- then double check all the things. -- and the actual answer to your question is to use the correct encoding for the contents of $value parameter, but then I fear that the language barrier is too high and the answer gets lost in transmission.